# How does one filter data based on user criteria in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, filter

I would like to add similar filters that can be found on ebay and bikeexchange.com.au that the client can use to narrow down their search criteria from an initial set of data.

I assume the best way to achieve this would be through jquery and by client-side calls containing the filter criteria on the initial data set that was return?

An existing example or tutorial would be great to learn from if you can recommend one?

Comment: There is no "standard practice". Why _would_ there be?

Comment: Because I thought it would be a common enough task to have one defined?

Comment: "You're new here, aren't you?" Outside of a given organization, nobody defines standard practices at all. Ever. Do you know of _any_ standard practices?

Comment: I just want to know what the best way to create filters like the ones on the above sites in asp.net. I don't want to go reinventing the wheel and I want to learn from other peoples experiences what the best way to accomplish this. Maybe standard practice is the wrong term to use maybe design pattern would be better?

Comment: Neither, I'm afraid. It all depends on your development environment and what's already being used where you are. If you are experimenting on your own, then you get to try different things out. They will all involve making a call to the server. Whether the server returns an entire page, or just the HTML of the changed table, or just returns the data and the table is rendered client-side through templates - those are all choices to make.